# Решение квадратного уравнения | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, уравнения

Необходимо решить квадратное уравнение

**Формат ввода**
Вводится 3 вещественных числа a, b, c — коэффициенты уравнения вида:
ax^2+bx+c=0ax

**Формат вывода**
Если у уравнения нет решений — следует вывести «No solution».
Если корней конечное число — их нужно вывести через пробел в порядке возрастания с точностью до сотых.
Если корней неограниченное число — следует вывести «Infinite solutions».

**Примечание**
Обратите внимание, что ограничения на значения коэффициентов отсутствуют.

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = float(input())
x1 = float(0.00)
x2 = float(0.00)
if a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 0:
    print("Infinite solutions")
elif a == 0 and b != 0 and c != 0:
    x1 = -(c / b)
    print("%.2f" % x1)
elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c != 0:
    print("No solution")  # no sol
elif a == 0 and b != 0 and c == 0:
    x1 = 0
    print("%.2f" % x1)
elif b == 0 and c == 0 and a != 0:
    x1 = 0
    print("%.2f" % x1)
elif c == 0 and b != 0 and a != 0:
    x1 = 0
    x2 = -(b / a)
    print(min("%.2f" % x1, "%.2f" % x2), max("%.2f" % x1, "%.2f" % x2), sep=' ')
elif b == 0 and a != 0 and c != 0:
    if (-(c / a)) < 0:
        print("No solution")
    else:
        x1 = (-c / a) ** 0.5
        x2 = -((-c / a) ** 0.5)
        print(min("%.2f" % x1, "%.2f" % x2), max("%.2f" % x1, "%.2f" % x2), sep=' ')
elif a != 0 and b != 0 and c != 0:
    disc = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)  # discriminant
    if disc < 0:
        print("No solution")
    elif disc == 0:
        x1 = (-b / (2 * a))
        print("%.2f" % x1)
    elif disc > 0:
        x1 = (-b - (disc ** 0.5)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b + (disc ** 0.5)) / (2 * a)
        print(min("%.2f" % x1, "%.2f" % x2), max("%.2f" % x1, "%.2f" % x2), sep=' ')
```

**Итог:**
13 тестов код проходит, а на 14-ом ловлю ошибку "Wrong answer(WA)"

UPD.Итог2.0:

Примитивная ликвидация %f форматтера спасла ситуацию и код прошёл все тесты, после чего на пол экрана проявилась табличка с зелёным шрифтом "Решена полностью". Спасибо всем причастным к решению моей проблемы как советами, так и комментариями, задачу требовалось решить зная лишь 3 типа данных, условные и логические операторы - задача выполнена. Рабочий код ниже:

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = float(input())
x1 = float(0.00)
x2 = float(0.00)
if a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 0:
    print("Infinite solutions")
elif a == 0 and b != 0 and c != 0:
    x1 = -(c / b)
    print(x1)
elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c != 0:
    print("No solution")  # no sol
elif a == 0 and b != 0 and c == 0:
    x1 = 0
    print(x1)
elif b == 0 and c == 0 and a != 0:
    x1 = 0
    print(x1)
elif c == 0 and b != 0 and a != 0:
    x1 = 0
    x2 = -(b / a)
    print(min(x1, x2), max(x1, x2), sep=' ')
elif b == 0 and a != 0 and c != 0:
    if (-(c / a)) < 0:
        print("No solution")
    else:
        x1 = (-c / a) ** 0.5
        x2 = -((-c / a) ** 0.5)
        print(min(x1, x2), max(x1, x2), sep=' ')
elif a != 0 and b != 0 and c != 0:
    disc = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)  # discriminant
    if disc < 0:
        print("No solution")
    elif disc == 0:
        x1 = (-b / (2 * a))
        print("%.2f" % x1)
    elif disc > 0:
        x1 = (-b - (disc ** 0.5)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b + (disc ** 0.5)) / (2 * a)
        print(min(x1, x2), max(x1, x2), sep=' ')
```

**Укороченный код:**

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = float(input())
x1 = float(0.00)
x2 = float(0.00)
if a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 0:
    print("Infinite solutions")
elif a == 0 and b != 0 and c != 0:
    x1 = -(c / b)   
    print(x1)
elif a == 0 and b == 0 and c != 0:
    print("No solution")  # no sol
elif a == 0 and b != 0 and c == 0:
    x1 = 0
    print(x1)
else:
    disc = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)  # discriminant
    if disc == 0:
        x1 = (-b) / (2 * a)
        print(x1)
    elif disc > 0:
        x1 = (-b - (disc ** 0.5)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b + (disc ** 0.5)) / (2 * a)
        print(min(x1, x2), max(x1, x2), sep=' ')
    elif disc < 0:
        print("No solution")
```

Comment: np.roots([a, b, c]).tolist()

Comment: np.roots возвращает корни многочлена по коэффициентам

Comment: Это решило вашу проблему?

Comment: @Эникейщик, добрый вечер! Решению квадратных уравнений обучали очень хорошо! Сможете предложить свой вариант кода? Я пока что дальше главы с условными операторами не ушёл ( прохожу хендбук от Яндекс), и использовать функции / опции языка, которые способствуют лучшей читаемости и меньшей ёмкости всего кода не научился(:

Comment: @Nikto, доброго Вам вечера! Предложенный Вами метод я не использовал, так как самостоятельно обнаружил ошибку ( использовал %f форматтер ). Спасибо за проявлений интерес к решению задачи (: 
По крайней мере ознакомлюсь с тем, что вы написали

Comment: Готовое решение нужно перенести в ответ. В вопросе должен быть только вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

вот общее решение квадратного уравнения

```
from cmath import *


def linear(a, b):
    solutions = set()
    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        solutions.add(True)

    if a == 0 and b != 0:
        solutions.add(False)

    if a != 0:
        solutions.add(-b / a)
    return solutions


def quadratic(a, b, c):
    solutions = set()
    if a != 0:
        D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        solutions.update({x1, x2})
    else:
        solutions.update(linear(b, c))
    return solutions


print('ax^2+bx+c=0')
a, b, c = map(complex, input().split())

print(quadratic(a, b, c))
```